# Understanding Conservation in Divergence Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem, divergence-theorem

Ok so I'm struggling with the concept of conservation in the divergence theorem.

Divergence theorem states that:
$$ \iiint_O {\nabla \cdot {\bf F}}\ dV = \iint_{S=\partial O} ({\bf F}\cdot \hat{{\bf n}}) d{S}$$

So, let's say your vector field had units of 1/length^2 (essentially a flux) - this means both quantities (right and left hand side of the equality) should give you the net total of some quantity (let's call it mass) passing through the boundary surface. In the case of isotropically outward emitting vector field (centered at the origin), I wouldn't expect, conceptually, that either of these integrals would change as you move outward in $r$ on a sphere (because your overall mass must be conserved).

That is, in the case I described, ${\bf F}=\hat{{\bf n}}$ and $\hat{{\bf n}}=x \hat{i}+y\hat {j}+z\hat{k}$ thus $\nabla \cdot {\bf F} = 1$ and $ \iiint_O {\nabla \cdot {\bf F}}\ dV = V$

##### So my question is, how is mass conserved if the total amount of mass crossing the surface increases as you consider a larger volume in the divergence theorem?

Comment: What makes you think that mass or anything is conserved? Whatever the fluid is whose motion is described by $\mathbf{F}\,,$ the right hand side tells you if the same amount that flows into $O$ will also flow out of $O$ or not. When the RHS is zero we can speak of conservation. If not we have either a sink or a source inside $O$ which is measured by divergence.

Comment: @KurtG. My assumption here is that the vector field is strictly oriented outward from the center of a sphere. Based on this, I *know* that the mass is strictly flowing out of $O$ and not back inward. The conservation in this case means that surface integrals (w/ source strength unchanged) over larger and larger spheres should yield the same value - right?

Comment: They should not. The divergence is constant equal to three inside any solid wherever you place it in $\mathbb R^3\,.$ So the flux through the boundary of that solid is proportional to its volume and always nonnegative. In other words: there are sources everywhere and they are homogeneously distributed.

Comment: Btw the field you're describing (point source, say at $0$, dumping something isotropically) is $\hat{r}/r^2$ (think why). This should align with your intuition: in this case, for any sphere centred at the origin, $\int_{\|x\| = R} F\cdot \hat{n} \mathrm{d}S = \int_{\|x\| = R} 1/R^2 \mathrm{d}S = 4\pi.$ The divergence of this field works out to $4\pi \delta(x)$, and the volume integral then yields the same quantity. Of course, for any surface not enclosing the origin, the LHS is $0$, which should confirm the convservation you were after.